# Proof that this set $\{f\in X\mid \|f\|_\infty \le 1\}$ is not compact in $C[0,1]$ with the sup norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X=C[0,1]$ with the $\sup$ norm. Let $Y = \{f\in X\mid \|f\|_\infty \le 1\}$. It is my goal to show that $Y$ is not compact using the sequence defintion of compactness. Note that it is very easy to show it using the covering defintion: Let $0$ denote the constant $0$ function. Then $B(0, 1- {1\over n})$ is an open cover of $Y$ that does not admit a finite subcover.

The sequence defintion states that a set is compact iff every sequence has a convergent subsequence. Therefore, to prove that $Y$ is not compact one must find a sequence that does not admit a convergent subsequence.

I tried and failed. Then I looked for a solution and found this: let $f_n (x) = x^n$. I do understand that $f_n \in Y$. But it seems that these functions only converge pointwise because the limit function is discontinuous. But for this proof one wants a sequence that converges uniformly to something not in $Y$, no? So this is not an answer.

Comment: $f_n$ does not converge to anything in $X$.  Neither does any subsequence.

Comment: $\{B(0, 1-\frac{1}{n})\}$ is **not** a cover, any function with norm exactly $1$ would not be in any such ball...

Comment: There is q general theorem (not hard) that in every  infinite dimensional Banach space the unit ball is not compact,.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to show that $Y$ is not closed, you want to show that $Y$ is not compact. That is, you don't want a sequence $(f_n)$ of members of $Y$ that converges to a limit $f$ such that $f \notin Y$ - that would prove that $Y$ is not closed, but $Y$ is closed (why?). You want a sequence $(f_n)$ that doesn't have any convergent subsequence and $f_n(x) = x^n$ provides such an example.

If $(f_n)$ had a convergent subseqence $(f_{n_k})$, then there would be $f \in Y$ such that $||f_{n_k} - f||_{\infty} \to 0$. That is, $(f_{n_k})$ would converge uniformly to $f$. Then $(f_{n_k})$ would also converge pointwise to $f$. But $(f_{n_k})$ converges pointwise to a discontinuous function, a contradiction to the fact that $f \in Y \subset C[0,1]$.